# What is the best way in this scenario to avoid a confused loop?

Tags: python, oop

So I wish to edit a list consisting of classes, this code is a simulation of two animals eating eachother. This function is about one animal (predator) eating the other animal (prey). To avoid that the loop becomes "messed up" when I remove one animal from the list, I decided to do it in this way:
The strongest predator should eat first and he is supposed to eat the weakest prey, checking the probability if he will try or not try to eat the prey.

```
def eat_predator(self):
    if len(self.specie_classes["Prey"]) > 0:
        self.specie_classes["Predator"].sort(
            key=lambda specie: specie.strength, reverse=True
        )
        for pred in self.specie_classes["Predator"]:
            prey_survivors= []
            food_apetite= pred.req['Apetite'] # This is how much food he wishes to eat
            current_food = 0
            self.specie_classes["Prey"].sort(
                key=lambda specie: specie.strength
            )
            for prey in self.specie_classes["Prey"]:
                if food_apetite >= current_food:
                    break

                if specie.determine_kill(prey):
                    current_food += prey.weight
                    pred.increase_eat_weight(prey.weight)
                    prey_survivors = [
                        surv_prey
                        for surv_prey in self.specie_classes["Prey"]
                        if surv_prey != prey
                    ]

            self.specie_classes["Prey"] = prey_survivors
```

This is my current solution, my main question is how can I avoid creating a new list each time I want to update the list containing Prey (animal) classes (without ruining the iteration)

This is what I wish to avoid:

```
d = list(range(10))
for n in d:
    print('Testing', n)
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        d.remove(n)
print(d)

Testing 0
Testing 2
Testing 4
Testing 6
Testing 8
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a list/set with the indices to be deleted, and then recreating `d` by excluding those indices:

```
In [74]: d = list(range(10))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [75]: deleteme = set()  # we'll track the indices to be deleted, here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [76]: for i,n in enumerate(d): 
    ...:     if n%2==0 or n%3==0: 
    ...:         deleteme.add(i)  # delete this index
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [77]: d = [e for i,e in enumerate(d) if i not in deleteme]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [78]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[78]: [1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: This is totally how I would approach this in C# as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of different alternatives.

1) Have an attribute called "isAlive" on each animal, and update that instead of removing the animal. By doing it this way, the iteration of the list will not be messed up.

2) Create a copy of the list, and then only delete animals from one copy. This way, the original order and indices are preserved.